# How can I decide if to add or not children also in the Update in real time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class GameObjectInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class GameObjectstInfo
    {
        public GameObject parent;
        public int childrenCount;
        public List<Transform> children = new List<Transform>();
    }

    public string gameObjectsInfo = "";
    public string results = "";
    public bool addChildren = false;
    public GameObjectstInfo[] objectsInfo;

    private string previousGameObjectsInfo = "";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Search();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (gameObjectsInfo != "" && gameObjectsInfo != previousGameObjectsInfo)
        {
            Search();
        }
        previousGameObjectsInfo = gameObjectsInfo;

        Reset();
    }

    public void Search()
    {
        if (gameObjectsInfo != "")
        {
            var foundObjects = FindGameObjectsWithName(gameObjectsInfo);
            objectsInfo = new GameObjectstInfo[foundObjects.Length];

            if (foundObjects.Length > 0)
            {
                results = "Found Results";
                for (int i = 0; i < foundObjects.Length; i++)
                {
                    objectsInfo[i] = new GameObjectstInfo();
                    objectsInfo[i].parent = foundObjects[i];

                    if (addChildren == true)
                    {
                        foreach (Transform t in foundObjects[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true))
                        {
                            objectsInfo[i].childrenCount += 1;
                            objectsInfo[i].children.Add(t);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                results = "No Results";
            }
        }
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        if (gameObjectsInfo == "")
        {
            results = "No Results";
            objectsInfo = new GameObjectstInfo[0];
        }
    }

    GameObject[] FindGameObjectsWithName(string nameIt)
    {
        int it = 0;
        GameObject[] objArr;
        bool b = false;
        while (!b)
        {
            if (GameObject.Find(nameIt))
            {
                GameObject.Find(nameIt).name = nameIt + it;
                it++;
            }
            else
            {
                b = true;
            }
        }

        objArr = new GameObject[it];
        while (it > 0)
        {
            it--;
            objArr[it] = GameObject.Find(nameIt + it);
            objArr[it].name = nameIt;
        }

        return objArr;
    }
}
```

This is the part where I'm adding or not the children:

```
if (addChildren == true)
{
    foreach (Transform t in foundObjects[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true))
    {
        objectsInfo[i].childrenCount += 1;
        objectsInfo[i].children.Add(t);
    }
}
else
{

}
```

But I want to do it also in the Update if the flag addChildren is true and changed to false or false to true make the change and add/remove the children in real time.

Now I need to delete the text in the variable gameObjectsInfo and re type again to make the children changes. But I want that the effect will happen without typing over again. Only when changing the state of the flag addChildren.

If I'm changing the addChildren state re search again with or without the children.

Comment: Where do you update `addChildren`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways you can do this by writing your own editor for the class so it'll respond to clicking on the checkbox for that bool, if you are only setting the value of `addChildren` through code, you can use a property `set` function, or, the most straight-forward way (if you don't mind waiting until the next frame after changing the value) is to just have an extra bool tracking the previous value:

```
private bool _lastAddChildren;
public bool addChildren = false;
...

void Start()
{
    _lastAddChildren = addChildren;
    ...
}

private void Update()
{
    if ((gameObjectsInfo != "" && gameObjectsInfo != previousGameObjectsInfo)
         || (_lastAddChildren != addChildren))
    {
        Search();
    }
    previousGameObjectsInfo = gameObjectsInfo;
    _lastAddChildren = addChildren;

    Reset();
}
```